# 'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

Tags: r, if-statement, shinyapps, coercion

I am getting above error whenever I am passing more than two conditions in if statement. I also tried 'all' instead of if statement but it also did not work.

**Error is** :

**Warning in distType == "All" && distType == "normal" :
'length(x) = 2 > 1' in coercion to 'logical(1)'**

**Here is my code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
```

## Add custom CSS to style the navigation bar color and alignment

ui = fluidPage(

```
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(width = 3,
  selectInput("Distribution","please select"
              ,choices = c("All","normal"), multiple = TRUE, selected = "All"),
  
  
),
mainPanel(
  
  forceNetworkOutput(outputId = "net")
)
```

))

server = function(input,output) {

Myclickaction = 'window.open(d.hyperlink, "_blank")'
output$net = renderForceNetwork({

```
    distType <- input$Distribution
    if(distType == "All" && distType == "normal"){

        fn <- forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes,
                   Source = "source", Target = "target", charge = -150,
                   opacityNoHover = 1, Nodesize = "size",
                   Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                   Group = "group", linkWidth = 2, clickAction =  Myclickaction,
                   opacity = 0.9,fontSize = 20, width = 1000,height = 700,linkDistance =  JS("function(d){return d.value * 40}"),colourScale =JS("d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);"),
                   zoom=TRUE)
fn$x$nodes$hyperlink <- MisNodes[["hyperlink"]]
fn
}else{

    MyClickScript <-'window.open("http://localhost:9191/"+ d.name, "_blank");'
    forceNetwork(Links = mislink, Nodes = misnod, Source = "source",
               Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",Nodesize = "size",
               Group = "group", opacity = 1, zoom = T,opacityNoHover = TRUE,
               fontSize = 20, width = 1000,height = 700,
               bounded = TRUE, clickAction = MyClickScript,linkDistance =100)
  
  }


})
```

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Comment: can you describe what you're aiming for with `distType == "All" && distType == "normal"`? as written his will always return FALSE or a vector of several FALSEs, depending on the length of `distType`

Comment: for example, `all(c("All","normal") %in% distType)` would check that both options are checked

Comment: `selectInput("Distribution","please select" ,choices = c("All","normal"), multiple = TRUE, selected = "All")`, 

Here, **'Distribution' ** is a Id which stores what user is selecting. 

`distType <- input$Distribution` I want if statement to be executed if and only if user selects both 'All' and 'normal' options from the dropdown. If I am providing only one condition within if statement for example 

`if(distType == "All")` Then it is working. But if I am trying to provide more than one condition within if statement, it is showing the same warning

Comment: Thank you so much @Miff

This code worked

if (all(c("All","normal") %in% distType)))

Thank you so much.